# Sistema de registro no guarda nada en la base de datos por error en while

Tags: php, mysql

Poseo el siguiente sistema de registro de datos, aunque parece que todo funciona bien, no inserta los datos en la base de datos:

Conexion.php

```
$cone = new mysqli($host,$usua,$pass,$base);

if ($cone->connect_errno) {
   echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $cone->connect_errno . ") " . $cone->connect_error;    
} 
?>
```

Registrar.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align ="center">Bienvenido</h1>
<a href ="index.html"><ol>Pagina Principal</ol></a>
<a href ="registrar.php"><ol>Registrar</ol></a>
<a href ="listado.php"><ol>Listado</ol></a>
<a href ="Sancion.php"><ol>Sancion</ol></a>
<form method="POST" action ="procesar.php">     
    <label> Ingrese su nombre </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese su apellido </label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese su cedula </label>
    <input type="text" name="cedula"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese su rango </label>
    <div><select name="rango">
        </select></div>
    <?php
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from rangos");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
echo '<option value="'.$reg[id_rango].'">'.$reg[rango].'</option>';
?>

    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Procesar.php

```
<?php    
  require_once'conexion.php';
  include'funciones.php';

  bd_agregar($_REQUEST);

?>

<html>
<a href="index.html"> VOLVER </a>
</html>
```

Funciones.php

```
    <?php
  require_once'conexion.php';

  //Creamos función
  function bd_agregar($d){
    //Especificamos variable global.
    global $cone;

    //Obtenemos datos formulario
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $rango = $_POST['rango'];

    //Insertamos datos
    $cone->query("INSERT INTO personal(nombre,apellido,cedula,rango_id) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");         
      echo $nombre.$apellido.$cedula.$rango;


  //Comprobamos ejecución sentencia.
  if ($cone===false) {
    printf("Mensaje de error: %s\n", $cone->error);
  } else {
    echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";

     $cone->close();
```

}
    ?>

Espero su ayuda :)

ERROR:

> El sistema muestra el mensaje "Los datos se insertaron correctamente", pero no inserta nada en la BD

Encontre el error. Ocurre que el valor "RANGO" no se guarda nada y por eso no pasa la query

Utilice este codigo para mostrar de datos que se encuentran en una BD.

```
 global $cone;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from rangos");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
echo "<option value='"$reg[id_rango]"'>".$reg[rango]."</option>";
```

y No pasa el Value, como podria solucionarlo

Comment: Añade el error claramente para que te puedan ayudar ... ya que en tu php dice "Aqui tienes el error de no insertar tus datos" no deja claro si sabes el error o no

Comment: se me paso eso jejeje gracias

Comment: insisto debes agregar el error que te muestra el servidor, cuando ejecutas tu php te muestra el error en el navegador o en postman (si lo usas) ya que solo colocas tus funciones php

Comment: listo, actualizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Corregi el listado del select

```
echo "<option value='$reg[id_rango]'>".$reg[rango]."</option>";
```

y el funciones.php

```
<?php
  require_once'conexion.php';

  //Creamos función
  function bd_agregar($d){
    //Especificamos variable global.
    global $cone;

    //Obtenemos datos formulario
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $rango = $_POST['rango'];
    echo $nombre."<br/>".$apellido."<br/>".$cedula."<br/>".$rango."<br/>";
    //Insertamos datos
    $cone->query("INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango_id) VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");         



  //Comprobamos ejecución sentencia.
  if ($cone===false) {
    printf("Mensaje de error: %s\n", $cone->error);
  } else {
    echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";
  }
   $cone->close(); 
   }
?>
```